# Layer data table with "depth from" and "depth to" columns. Using SQL to add data to "depth from" based on "depth to" entries

Tags: sql, oracle, join, inner-join

I got a table with layer data. As an example I got 3 Objects, every one of them got few layers (soil).

I would like to somehow use an join with the table itself, to get the empty "depth from" cells filled. My Idea was a shifted join based on row counts. Any ideas how to realise that with SQL for a noob like me?

My Table looks like that:

| OBJID | LAYID | DEPTHFROM | DEPTHTTO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | NULL | 0,3 |
| 1 | 1 | NULL | 1,4 |
| 1 | 2 | NULL | 2,8 |
| 1 | 3 | NULL | 3,6 |
| 2 | 0 | NULL | 0,6 |
| 2 | 1 | NULL | 0,9 |
| 2 | 2 | NULL | 1,1 |
| 2 | 3 | NULL | 2,2 |
| 3 | 0 | NULL | 0,5 |
| 3 | 1 | NULL | 2,4 |
| 3 | 2 | NULL | 3,9 |

Usually the first Layer of an Object begins at 0.

The desired result would be:

| OBJID | LAYID | DEPTHFROM | DEPTHTTO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0,3 |
| 1 | 1 | 0,3 | 1,4 |
| 1 | 2 | 1,4 | 2,8 |
| 1 | 3 | 2,8 | 3,6 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 0,6 |
| 2 | 1 | 0,6 | 0,9 |
| 2 | 2 | 0,9 | 1,1 |
| 2 | 3 | 1,1 | 2,2 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 0,5 |
| 3 | 1 | 0,5 | 2,4 |
| 3 | 2 | 2,4 | 3,9 |

I would be very happy for some good ideas.

The table sits on an oracle db.

Thank you in advance for every help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select OBJID, LAYID,
       nvl (lag(DEPTHTTO) over (partition by OBJID order by LAYID), 0) as DEPTHFROM,
       DEPTHTTO
from mytable;
```

Comment: Corrected - `lag` not `lead`.  Why can I never remember which is which?!